# List as per the type of argument

Tags: scala

Below I have:

```
trait Elem {
  def compare: Int
}

case class DiffElem(weight: Int, len: Int) extends Elem {
  def compare = weight - len;
}
```

Now there can be many sub-classes of Elem, based on the `compare` function.
Now I have a function, that reads input from file and generates a list of `DiffElem`:

```
def getInput[T <: Elem](): List[T] = {
  var ans: List[T] = List.empty[T]
  for (line <- Source.fromFile("src/week1/jobs.txt").getLines()) {
    val diff = line.split(" ")
    ans = ans match{
      case i:List[DiffElem] =>  new DiffElem(Integer.parseInt(diff(0)), Integer.parseInt(diff(1))) :: ans;
      case _ => ???
    }

  }
  ans
}
```

But the compiler does not allow the operation, obviously as `::` follows contra-variance type and I am trying to do invariance. If I convert the function signature to `T >: Elem` then it works, but the purpose is not solved.

Any better approach??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're constructing DiffElem inside getInput, then how (and why) do you want to get list of arbitrary T <: Elem? To do something like this, you should be able to convert from DiffElem to any another T <: Elem, and that convertability could be captured with implicit like this:

```
  def getInput[T <: Elem](implicit conv: DiffElem => T): List[T] = ...
```

, but do you really want it? If you'll be happy with just list of DiffElem's, you could rewrite your function in functional style this way:

```
  def getInput(): List[DiffElem] =
    Source.fromFile("src/week1/jobs.txt").getLines().map { line =>
      val diff = line.split(" ")
      DiffElem(
        Integer.parseInt(diff(0)),
        Integer.parseInt(diff(1))
      )
    } toList
```

[map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29) is higher-order function that captures transformation of each element of sequence into the result of application of its funarg to this element.

**Update**:
To make modular type-driven list creation I'll suggest implicits:

```
  def getInput[E <: Elem](implicit mkE: (Int, Int) => E): List[E] = {
    Source.fromFile("src/week1/jobs.txt").getLines().map { line =>
      val diff = line.split(" ")      
      mkE(diff(0).toInt, diff(1).toInt)      
    } toList
  }
```

Now, for any E <: Elem, list of which you want to get, you should provide implicit value of type (Int, Int) => E into the scope, like:

```
  implicit val diffElemBuilder = {
    (a, b) => DiffElem(a, b)
  }
```

And in any scope, where this implicit is visible, you could use getInput like this:

```
val xs = getInput[DiffElem]
```

Comment: With this, it will create a list of DiffElem. What if there existed another class that extends Elem and I want to create a list of that? I tried doing ti by Pattern Matching, as based on the type of generic, I could generate the list

Comment: Hm, do you want some sort of type-driven list creation: to use getInput with explicit type parameter to get lists of different types (like getInput[DiffElem]() to get list of DiffElem's and getInput[AnotherElem]() to get list of AnotherElems)?

Answer (score -1):

You might restructure the code and use higher-ranked polymorphic functions instead of the pattern matching.